# Real as an adverb and adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

**Real** can be used as adjective as well as adverb.

As an adverb meaning of **real** is **very**

Therefore I think its usage in the following sentence is correct

> The **real** important thing to remember is that language learning requires a lot of practice.

But according to my book it is wrong and instead **really** should be used.

Comment: Your book is correct in that the use of _real_ to mean _very_ is described by Oxford Dictionaries as 'Informal, North American'. If your sentence is for a piece of written work I would advise you to use _really_.

Answer (score 1):

Your book is correct in that the use of "real" to mean very is described by Oxford Dictionaries as 'Informal, North American'. If your sentence is for a piece of written work I would advise you to use "really". –
Kate Bunting

Answer (score 0):

It should be "really important," because "really" is an adverb that modifies the adjective "important."

Adjectives modify nouns, so you can say a "real thing," but they do not modify other adjectives, so you can's say a "real important thing."

Comment: You might want to take that up with Merriam-Webster which lists [real](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/real) as both adjective and adverb.

Answer (score -1):

The adjective is "real." The adverb is "really." In English, the -ly ending is a good indicator of an adverb.

Adjective -- modifying nouns:

This is real beef (not a plant-based substitute).

He is a real scientist.

Adverb -- modifying verbs:

I really love eating beef.

He really does scientific research.

His research is really important. (Even though it follows the verb 'is')

Comment: Note that while adverbs do commonly end in *-ly*, not all of them do. And flat adverbs are also used idiomatically, even though some people object. The classic example is road signs that tell people to *drive* ***slow*** rather than *drive* ***slowly***. *It's **really** important* is fine, but, although less natural, people do also say *it's **real** important*, making use of the adjective as a flat adverb.

Comment: Absolutely, good comments. People should be aware that 'it's real important' is not for professional(ly) written materials.